# Windows Rebooting to Blackscreen after removing WUBI

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, shutdown, reboot

I wanted to install Ubuntu and Win 8.1 in DualBoot. I used Wubi to install Ubuntu. After rebooting and not accessing Ubuntu I removed Wubi.
Now my Acer Aspire V2-772G does not restart. 
Using bootrec.exe /fixmbr and /fixboot and /rebuidbcd do not fix the problem.
It starts the process to shutdown but it stays in a blackscreen and nothing happens anymore... so it ends up in a blackscreen of nothingness.
Thank you so far.
Regards j0chn
Edit:
It seems that the command on restart is active (e.g. I wanted to reboot into advanced boot options for debug mode, so I restartet the Laptop. But it did not shutdown so I pressed the power button and after booting it again the advanced booting options appeared), so my conclusion is, that it just don't shutdown properly.

Comment: Wubi does not work with Windows 8, so you should not be using it in the first place. If you don't want to risk a full install, try using a virtual machine instead. I recommend VirtualBox, personally.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. Problem is, that I need it on a real machine, because I want to access my nexus with ubuntu touch and a virtual machine does not recognize the phone...

Comment: VirtualBox actually does have options for enabling interfacing with external hardware. Alternatively, you could just install Ubuntu from a LiveCD and choose Install Alongside Windows 8 when prompted.

Comment: Hm I used VMPlayer and not VB. Maybe I will try this later. The "beside" option is unfortunately not available and I try to install Ubuntu with partitioning atm. But my problem is that windows 8.1d oes not shutdown my laptop properly :(

Comment: To shut down Windows 8 properly, you need to open your Charms Bar, click the Settings Icon, then click the Power Icon, then shift-click the Restart option instead of clicking the Shut Down option. Wait a bit for a menu to pop up, and then you can select the shut down option to fully shut down your computer.